# Gem::LoadError: can't activate selenium-webdriver (>= 4.0.0) RSpec Rails 7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, selenium-webdriver

I'm getting a weird issue where selenium-webdriver is not respecting the selected version number for the gem and its causing my specs to fail, overall. I can't seem to stop it, even after uninstalling the gems and reinstalling them with the selected versions. I'm running all of this on docker and its hard to track where the issue is coming from. **How do I get selenium-webdriver-3.142.7 to be the only choice for running my acceptance tests?**

**Error:**

```
Failures:

  1) Landing Page Navigation shows header
     Failure/Error: raise e
     
     Gem::LoadError:
       can't activate selenium-webdriver (>= 4.0.0), already activated selenium-webdriver-3.142.7. Make sure all dependencies are added to Gemfile.
     # /usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-2.4.1/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:276:in `block (2 levels) in replace_gem'
     # /usr/local/bundle/gems/actionpack-7.0.2.2/lib/action_dispatch/system_testing/driver.rb:24:in `initialize'
     # /usr/local/bundle/gems/actionpack-7.0.2.2/lib/action_dispatch/system_test_case.rb:159:in `new'
     # /usr/local/bundle/gems/actionpack-7.0.2.2/lib/action_dispatch/system_test_case.rb:159:in `driven_by'
     # /usr/local/bundle/gems/rspec-rails-6.0.1/lib/rspec/rails/example/system_example_group.rb:99:in `driven_by'
     # /usr/local/bundle/gems/rspec-rails-6.0.1/lib/rspec/rails/example/system_example_group.rb:94:in `block in initialize'
     # /usr/local/bundle/gems/rspec-core-3.12.1/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:457:in `instance_exec'
     # /usr/local/bundle/gems/rspec-core-3.12.1/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:457:in `instance_exec'
     # /usr/local/bundle/gems/rspec-core-3.12.1/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:365:in `run'
     # /usr/local/bundle/gems/rspec-core-3.12.1/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:529:in `block in run_owned_hooks_for'
     # /usr/local/bundle/gems/rspec-core-3.12.1/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:528:in `each'
     # /usr/local/bundle/gems/rspec-core-3.12.1/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:528:in `run_owned_hooks_for'
     # /usr/local/bundle/gems/rspec-core-3.12.1/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:615:in `block in run_example_hooks_for'
     # /usr/local/bundle/gems/rspec-core-3.12.1/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:614:in `reverse_each'
     # /usr/local/bundle/gems/rspec-core-3.12.1/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:614:in `run_example_hooks_for'
     # /usr/local/bundle/gems/rspec-core-3.12.1/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:484:in `run'
     # /usr/local/bundle/gems/rspec-core-3.12.1/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:505:in `run_before_example'
     # /usr/local/bundle/gems/rspec-core-3.12.1/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:261:in `block in run'
     # /usr/local/bundle/gems/rspec-core-3.12.1/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:511:in `block in with_around_and_singleton_context_hooks'
     # /usr/local/bundle/gems/rspec-core-3.12.1/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:468:in `block in with_around_example_hooks'
     # /usr/local/bundle/gems/rspec-core-3.12.1/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:486:in `block in run'
     # /usr/local/bundle/gems/rspec-core-3.12.1/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:626:in `block in run_around_example_hooks_for'
     # /usr/local/bundle/gems/rspec-core-3.12.1/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:352:in `call'
     # /usr/local/bundle/gems/rspec-rails-6.0.1/lib/rspec/rails/example/system_example_group.rb:120:in `block (2 levels) in <module:SystemExampleGroup>'
```

**Gemfile**

```
group :development, :test do
  # See https://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html#debugging-with-the-debug-gem
  gem "debug", platforms: %i[ mri mingw x64_mingw ]
  gem "rspec-rails"
  gem "factory_bot_rails"
  gem "faker"
end

group :development do
  # Use console on exceptions pages [https://github.com/rails/web-console]
  gem "web-console"
  gem 'letter_opener_web', '~> 2.0'
  # Add speed badges [https://github.com/MiniProfiler/rack-mini-profiler]
  # gem "rack-mini-profiler"

  # Speed up commands on slow machines / big apps [https://github.com/rails/spring]
  # gem "spring"
end

group :test do
  # Use system testing [https://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#system-testing]
  gem "capybara"
  gem 'selenium-webdriver', '~> 3.142.7'
  gem "webdrivers"
end
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
services:
  web:
    build: .
    command: bash -c "rm -f tmp/pids/server.pid && bin/rails s -p 3001 -b '0.0.0.0' && rails tailwindcss:watch"
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app
      - bundle:/usr/local/bundle
    ports:
      - "3001:3001"
      - "80:80"
    env_file:
      - .env
    environment:
      - HISTFILE=/usr/src/app/log/.bash_history
      - HUB_HOST=hub:4444
    depends_on:
      - db
      - redis
  hub:
    image: selenium/hub:3.8.1
    environment:
      GRID_BROWSER_TIMEOUT: 10000 # 10 seconds
      GRID_NEW_SESSION_WAIT_TIMEOUT: 20000
      GRID_NODE_POLLING: 300
      GRID_TIMEOUT: 10000
    ports:
      - "4444:4444"
  node-chrome:
    image: selenium/node-chrome:3.8.1
    environment: &SELENIUM_NODE_ENV
      HUB_HOST: hub
      HUB_PORT: 4444
    ports:
      - "5901:5901"
    volumes:
      - /dev/shm:/dev/shm
```

**capybara.rb**

```
require 'capybara'
Capybara.register_driver :chrome_headless do |app|
  chrome_capabilities = ::Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.chrome('goog:chromeOptions' => { 'args': %w[no-sandbox headless disable-gpu window-size=1400,1400] })

  if ENV['HUB_URL']
    Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app,
                                   browser: :remote,
                                   url: "http://#{ENV['HUB_HOST']}/wd/hub",
                                   capabilities: chrome_capabilities)
  else
    Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app,
                                   browser: :chrome,
                                   capabilities: chrome_capabilities)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your gemfile.lock it's hard to say. But the error is telling you you're trying to load 2 conflicting versions of selenium-webdriver

Comment: Something changes when docker runs selenium -- its pointing to the wrong gem.  I'm just going to put this on the shelf until I find a working solution for capybara/docker/selenium hub

Comment: Run `gem list selenium-webdriver`